# Unable to create typescript class object

Tags: class, oop, typescript, object, new-operator

New to typescript, I came across Typescript class like the following.

```
export class Errors {
    errors: { [key: string]: string } = {};
}
```

I am trying to create this error object manually. Can you show usage of this?  i tried the following.

```
errList: Errors = new Errors();

errList = {'key':'value'};

errList = [
      {
        Key: "code1",
        value: "err1"
      },
      {
        Key: "code2",
        value: "err2"
      },
    ]

errList.errors = {
    [key1]:"myValueX" , [key3]:"myValueY"
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize the class as you declared it you would have to use :

```
var err = new Errors();
err.errors = {
    "key": "value"
};
```

Another alternative would be to also define a constructor then you could initialize like this:

```
export class Errors {
    constructor(public errors: { [key: string]: string } = {}){};
}

var err = new Errors({
    "key": "value"
});
```

If you do not have any errors on the class you could also use an interface instead and then you wouldn't need a constructor and you could just use object literals to initialize:

```
export interface  Errors {
    errors: { [key: string]: string };
}

var err: Errors = {
    errors: {  "key": "value" }
};
```

Which one you choose is a matter of preference and your use case. I would go for the constructor version, as is the most concise to initialize but also lets you use the `instanceof` operator, which the interface version does not.

Comment: Thank you for the options...the constructor version works best for me as well.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your class:

```
export class Errors {
    errors: { [key: string]: string } = {};
}
```

has a data member `errors`, but you only do this:

```
errList: Errors = new Errors();
errList = {'key':'value'};
```

Try doing this instead for the second line:

```
errList.errors = {'key', 'value'};
```